# getting 206 partial content while loading .mp3 files

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, apache

I have a web app that loads instagram images and creates a slideshow with background sound. While the images are being loaded, a pre loader is run to show the processing. But it doesn't fully load the mp3 file and when I check in the browser's console it has got `206 partial content`. So, on clicking the play button, I have to wait a few second so that music is loaded fully to play the slideshow.

```
 console.log('loading theme: ' + folder);
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });

    $.when(
            $.getScript(epic.getFrontendURL() + "animations/" + folder +  "/js/data.js"),
            $.getScript(epic.getFrontendURL() + "animations/" + folder + "/js/main.js"),
            $.Deferred(function (deferred) {
                $(deferred.resolve);
            })
        ).done(function () {
 //some methods
  sound_bg.src = epic.getFrontendURL() + "sound/back.mp3?
  });
```

So, is this related somehow, with `done` which delays the processing.

Comment: why do you need to set the `mp3` source after other scripts loaded since it appears you already have the url beforehand?

Comment: These scripts load the main theme of slideshow, so after they finish loading, i am loading the mp3 file, but why its getting 206 partial content, also the backend server is windows

Comment: don't need the whole file to start streaming

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is normal. Browsers use HTTP range requests to load audio and video files to minimize bandwidth usage.

If you want the browser to preload the audio, set the `preload` attribute to `auto` on the audio element:

```
<audio src="..." preload="auto"></audio>
```

Comment: After loading the audio in this tag. Do I continue to use the audio tag normally like this? `const audio = new Audio('source/a.mp3') audio.play()`. I suppose I also need  to load the javascript that will play my audio after these tags? I tried what I thought, but in some reloads I'm still getting the ERR_CACHE_READ_FAILURE 206

Comment: `Browsers use HTTP range requests to load audio and video files to minimize bandwidth usage.` What do you mean ? Loading audio over https can't work ?

Comment: @Emeric HTTP Range request is specific to the HTTP protocol. Loading audio over HTTPS will work fine.

What HTTP Range request does it that it will only request just a part of the audio file to save the network bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to check if there are errors, if there are sound errors, your website will reload the faulty sound, until it's loaded right. This has worked for me:

```
var sound1 = new Audio('sfx/1.mp3')
var sound2 = new Audio('sfx/2.mp3')
var sound3 = new Audio('sfx/3.mp3')

var soundChecker = setInterval(function() {
    if (sound1.error) {
        sound1 = new Audio('sfx/1.mp3')
    } else if (sound2.error) {
        sound2 = new Audio('sfx/2.mp3')
    } else if (sound3.error) {
        sound3 = new Audio('sfx/3.mp3')
    } else {
        clearInterval(soundChecker)
    }
}, 1500)
```

This will check for errors when loading sounds every one and a half seconds (you could modify the time for slower connections), if there is an error with any of the loaded sounds, soundChecker will reload them until all sounds have been loaded successfully (without errors). If all sounds have been loaded successfully the soundChecker interval will clear itself and stop checking.

You will notice that errors such as `net::ERR_CACHE_READ_FAILURE 206 (Partial Content)` will still be printed in the console but the sound will work, because in a following reload it was successfully loaded.